# How to escape hash sign in handlebars?

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I'm using an external API that I can't change, that amongst others returns a list of images as so:

```
"image": [
    {"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/24816431.jpg", "size": "small"},
    {"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/24816431.jpg", "size": "medium"},
    {"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/24816431.jpg", "size": "large"},
    {"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/24816431.jpg", "size": "extralarge"},
    {"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/24816431/Art+Brut+street.jpg", "size": "mega"}
],
```

However, when trying to use one of the images in handlebars via {{image.2.#text}} it throws a wobbly because of the hash symbol.

Anyone have any ideas how ot get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars is intentionally simple so there's not a lot you can within the template. However, just because some external API is feeding you ugliness doesn't mean you have to use it as-is. I'd beat some sense into the data in JavaScript before anything gets to the template, something simple like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < image.length; ++i) {
    image[i].text = image[i]['#text'];
    delete image[i]['#text'];
}
```

will let your template talk about `{{image.2.text}}` and your problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Last.fm API using Backbone and Hanledbars and this got it working in the template:

```
<img src="{{ image.[1].[#text] }}" alt="{{ realname }}" />
```